# Testing Angular 2 with Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs

So I am trying to switch from Karma to Jest. I cant seem to get Jest to run on my windows machine. I have it working for the mac though.

I followed: https://www.xfive.co/blog/testing-angular-faster-jest/

Here's what I am seeing: (it just sits here)
[image]

My package.json has this as the jest config:

`"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts",
    "globals": {
      "__TS_CONFIG__": "tsconfig.json"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/src/.*|(\\.|/))\\.spec\\.ts?$"
  }`

Like I said, I can get this to work for the mac, but for windows it is not working, just sits at the above image.. Any ideas?

Comment: can we see your setupJest.ts file? and if by any chance you can create a repo on github with what you have so far this could help

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason is some kind of incompatibility when running Windows console applications from BASH. To verify, just run your npm scripts through Window's native command prompt.

You can utilize `winpty` to run Windows console applications through Git BASH. In my case I have to enter the full path to the program to run *and* use `npm.cmd`, even through Git BASH. In my case however, the Node installatin is NOT in the global PATH. So from Git BASH, run:

```sh
winpty <BASH-compatible path to Node installation>/npm.cmd test
```